# How to add space between table and text

Tags: html

How can I add space between table border (all sides) and text. Tried with padding but that didn't work. Is there any way to add space?

**CSS**

```
.border1 {
  border-top:thin solid;
  border-bottom:thin solid;
  border-left:thin solid;
  border-right:thin solid;
  border-color:black;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table class="formLayout" width="81%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td class="border1">
        <b><font size="3" face="Arial"><p>Message to display</p></font></b>                                                         
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Define "didn't work". Did you inspect the element to make sure the padding was taking effect? Padding is indeed the way to add space between the contents and perimiter of an element.

Comment: @Utkanos: so how can add space between the border and text. Got it through Div but i can't change any of the code. so got stuck here.

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing more space on top and bottom due to `<p>`.
Remove `<p>` and then you can increase the `padding` 
Or else you can use like below.

```
padding: 5px 10px;
```

It will add `5px` `padding` on top and bottom and `10px` on left and right

Answer (score 1):

`padding` is the way to add space between text content and border.

I have cleaned your code so that you can see the effect. Use following code and see the effect

**Style**

```
.table-border {
        border:1px solid black;
        padding: 10px;  
        border-collapse: collapse;      
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<table width="81%" cellspacing="0" class="table-border">
            <tr>
                <td class="table-border" >
                    One
                </td>  
                <td class="table-border" >
                    Two
                </td>   
            </tr>

      </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course you could always add margin to the paragraph instead, something like:

```
.formLayout tr td.border1 p{
   margin: 5px;
}
```

Then you could remove that horrible font tag and b tag and use the p styling instead for the desired results:

```
.formLayout tr td.border1 p{
   margin: 5px;
   font-family: Arial;
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "align-text: center" to center your "p" like this:

```
p {
    text-align: center;
    }
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/6gw5hpfx/)

Answer (score 0):

You can fix that using `padding-left` property in CSS for the `<p>`.

**Working Code Snippet:**

```css
.border1 {
  border-top:thin solid;
  border-bottom:thin solid;
  border-left:thin solid;
  border-right:thin solid;
  border-color:black;
  padding: 5px;
}

p{
  padding-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<table class="formLayout" width="81%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td class="border1">
      <b><font size="3" face="Arial"><p>Message to display</p></font></b>
    </td>       
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

**Read up:** [`padding-left` - CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-left)

---

**P.S.** To get the text aligned in the center, use `text-align: center;` in the CSS for `p`.

Answer (score 0):

For me the padding is working just check it

```
<table class="formLayout" width="81%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
    <td class="border1">
    <b><font size="3" face="Arial"><p>Message to display</p>   </font></b>                                                         
    </td>
</tr>
 </table>


  .border1 {
 border-top:thin solid;
 border-bottom:thin solid;
 border-left:thin solid;
    border-right:thin solid;
    border-color:black;

   padding: 18px 122px 11px;

}
```

The Fiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/635tfeLx/

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

```
.border1 {
      border-top:thin solid;
      border-bottom:thin solid;
      border-left:thin solid;
      border-right:thin solid;
      border-color:black;
      border-color: darkred;
      border-style: solid;
      color: red;
      padding: 5px 15px;    
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<table class="formLayout" width="81%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border:2px;">
<tr>
    <td class="border1">    
        <b><font size="3" face="Arial"><p>Message to display</p></font></b>                                                 
    </td>
     </tr>
</table>
```